# can't install phpPgAdmin with cwp

Tags: php, postgresql, phppgadmin, php-pgsql, cwp

I am using cwp on my VPS and I have this problem when I try to login to https://hostname:2031/phpPgAdmin/
The PHP configuration on this server does not support PostgreSQL. You need to reinstall PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option.

i tried to fix it by doing the next

I have php7.4.3 and extensions are enabled from the CWP control panel

```
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
```

And I installed the packages

```
php-pgsql
php-pdo
```

uncomment

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=_pgsql
```

in File: /usr/local/php/php.ini

reload apache, Nginx , Postgresql

and still have the same problem

Comment: `_pgsql` doesn't look familiar. Check your PHP ext directory and `grep` for `pgsql` to check that is the correct extension name. `ls -rvla /path/to/php/etc | grep pgsl`